# How do I compile vb code to exe?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have some vb code that is structured like this:

```
./AssemblyInfo.vb
./WindowsApplication1/AppUtils.vb
./WindowsApplication1/Form1.vb
./WindowsApplication1.Form1.resx
./WindowsApplication1.My/MyApplication.vb
./WindowsApplication1.My/MyComputer.vb
./WindowsApplication1.My/MyProject.vb
./WindowsApplication1.My/MySettings.vb
./WindowsApplication1.My/MySettingsProperty.vb
./WindowsApplication1.My.Resources/Resources.vb
./WindowsApplication1.Resources.resx
./WindowsApplication1.vbproj
```

I have tried several times trying to create an empty solution and then import the .vb and the .vbproj but I can not stumble on the right combination to get it to expose the build button on the menu so we can build it.

I am not a windows person so googling is difficult because the terminology is difficult to understand: Example: I use the New Project button to create a solution; that is confusing.

In short, I am hoping to get instructions that will cover:

A) Creating a new solution,

B) Importing the code listed above into the solution, and

C) Compiling the code into an .exe.

BTW: I am using Visual Studio 2008.

If you give me you best guess I will edit your answer as I try it and figure out more precise instructions.

[EDIT] When I double click on the .vbproj file on windows explorer visual studio opens and the .vbproj file is displayed as XML.  No build button is shown.

[EDIT] When I do File -> Open Project... .vbproj is not listed as a supported extension so there is no way to load the project from that menu item. That menu items does not have a *.* all source option.  The .vbproj file has an icon that indicates that windows knows what it is: "Visual Basic Project file". This code is the result of a decompiling an .exe of the original project where the source was lost.

[EDIT] I just followed Joel's advice, but I used VS2005 rather than VS2008 and it was able to find the .vbproj file.  Does that make sense?  Is there something wrong with my VS2008 that makes it not open .vbproj files or is that to be expected?

[EDIT] The version of VS that CANNOT see the .vbproj is VS2008 9.0.30729.4462.  The version of VS that CAN see the .vbproj is VS2005 8.0.50727.762.  By "see" I mean when I follow Joel's instructions of using File->Open Project VS will recognize the .vbproj file as something it can open.

Comment: You already have the `.vbproj` file - just open it and then Use `Build`->`Build Solution` in the menu. Does that not work? I assume that the project file contains the references to the files in your question and it is compatible with VS 2008.

Comment: Opening the project file will create a new solution for you if there's no `.sln` file in the folders.

Comment: To address one bit of confusion: in the VS world, a 'solution' consists of one or more projects; each project will compile into one .exe.

Comment: You said when you try to open the project in VS that `.vbproj` is not listed as an extension.  Which version of Visual Studio are you using exactly?  Can you check _Help -> About_ to get the exact version name and number that you are using?  Open the Visual Studio command prompt and type **devenv /installvstemplates** and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I double click on the .vbproj file on windows explorer visual studio opens and the .vbproj file is displayed as XML

Something is broken with file associations on your Windows system.

You can open Visual Studio first and choose "Open Project/Solution" inside Visual Studio. Doing this will makes sure Visual Studio treats it as a project file, rather than just an XML file, and will allow you to attempt to build the project.

BTW, recent versions of Visual Studio are free. You might be able to fix this by updating to a more recent version.